# CUDA 8 or 9/9.1 for GeForce GT 750M/Ubuntu/GeForce GT 750M

Tags: 16.04

I am installing Pytoarch on Ubuntu 16.04. I am not sure which CUDA should I install for GeForce GT 750M . CUDA 8 or CUDA 9/9.1?

Answer (score 0):

Your Geforce GT 750M has a compute capability of 3.0, so it supports CUDA 9.0/9.1.  Unless you need to be compatible with CUDA 8.0 for some reason, I'd go with the latest your card supports, for efficiency if for no other reason.